# Which bluetooth connection type is the right one to choose?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, gatt, rfcomm

I have a Samsung Gear S3 (running Tizen) with a selfmade web-app for logging Data from the heartrate monitor as well as from the Pedometer to a .csv-file. I would like to send each line in the .csv via Bluetooth to an UWP App. As I am a total beginner with C# and Bluetooth connections, I am struggling to understand the basic concepts of the different connection modes.

So here my question: In my specific usecase, would I choose RFCOMM, GATT or LE?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a vast Issue. I would suggest you to check out this post for now:

[GATT over SPP profile for bluetooth communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135438/gatt-over-spp-profile-for-bluetooth-communication)